# Can a css variable name start with a number?

Tags: css, syntax, w3c-validation, css-variables

I want to know if it is valid to define a css variable that starts with a number like this,

```
:root { --1space: 32px; }
```

this works just fine with Chrome, however that code is not being validated by https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ also VSCode draws a red line under the variable name.

if css variable names are idents then it should be ok to start with a number by this diagram;

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#ident-token-diagram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's valid. If we follow [the definition in the speficiation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#defining-variables):

> A custom property is any property whose name starts with two dashes (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), like `--foo`. The `<custom-property-name>` production corresponds to this: it’s defined as any valid identifier that starts with two dashes

And

> identifier
>
> A portion of the CSS source that has the same syntax as an `<ident-token>`. Also appears in `<at-keyword-token>`, `<function-token>`, `<hash-token>` with the "id" type flag, and the unit of `<dimension-token>`.

[image]

```css
:root {
 --2222:red;
}

body {
  background:var(--2222);
}
```