# Is "--" a valid CSS3 identifier?

Tags: css, language-lawyer, specifications

According the CSS Level 3 [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#check-if-three-code-points-would-start-an-identifier), for parsing the start of an identifier, you:

**Check if three code points would start an identifier**

Look at the first code point:

- If the first character is `-`, then we have a valid identifier if:

  1. The second code point is an identifier-start code point (`[a-zA-Z_]` or non-ASCII).
  2. The second code point is `-`.
  3. The second and third character form a valid escape.

Otherwise, we do not have a valid identifier start. After determining if we have a valid identifier start, the only requirements to have a valid `<ident-token>` is we have 0 or more of any combination of the following:

1. Escape tokens
2. ASCII letters
3. Digits
4. `_` or `-`
5. Non-ASCII characters

Since we do not require any characters following an identifier start token, this would suggest that `--` is a valid identifier, even if never supported by any browser or framework. However, even official CSS validation [services](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) (maintained by those that design the CSS specifications) do not consider this a valid identifier. Is this merely a bug in the validation service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--` custom property identifier [is reserved for future use](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#custom-property), but current browsers incorrectly treat it as a valid custom property.

See also

- [w3c/csswg-drafts#6313](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6313)

Answer (score 8):

It's not more valid now.

---

Yes it's valid and it works. It's the shortest custom property (aka CSS variable) that you can define:

```css
body {
 --:red;
 background:var(--);
}
```

Related: [Can a css variable name start with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66941906/8620333)

Comment: So are you suggesting that those official CSS validation services are bugged? Or is this just technically valid but practically invalid in some way?

Comment: @RobinBastiaan they aren't bugged but they are rarely updated to consider new stuff. A lot of valid *new* things will fail in the validator. What I am showing is perfectly valid and you can use it with no issue (even if not recommended as a good practise)

Comment: I think setting the background of `body` to `red` is almost always good practice.