# string of only numbers not parsed correctly by CSS

Tags: javascript, css, font-face, css-variables

`font.newFileName` is a string of only numbers: `'000001101'`, `'000001102'`, `'000001103'`, so on and so forth.

If `font.newFileName` in `new FontFace` and `setProperty` is prefixed with a letter or changed to `a${font.newFileName}`, the script works...

```
...

fontList.forEach(font => {

  const
    ff = new FontFace(font.newFileName, `url('${font.newFilePath.replace(/\\/g, '/')}')`),
    fontItem = fontItemTemplate.content.cloneNode(true),
    fontNameElement = fontItem.querySelector('.font-name')

  ff.load().then(
    () => document.fonts.add(ff),
    err => console.error('ERROR:', err)
  )

  fontNameElement.style.setProperty('--font-family', font.newFileName)
  fontNameElement.style.fontFamily = 'var(--font-family)'

  ...
```

Does anybody know why this is the case?

Also, is there some way to use the `font.newFileName` values as they are without having to prefix a letter to the front?

Comment: Hi My initial answer might have worked for you because in it I was using `\`fontNameElement.style.setProperty(\`--${key}\`, \`'${map.get(key)}'\`);` the quotes. but my explanation and understanding was not right(in my initial answer which was pointed out in another answer). Please take a look at the other answer, that is the correct explanation and you can accept that since that is the correct reason for your issue. thanks. Once you unaccept. I will remove my post since it might be misleading to keep the older answer (as suggested in my answers comment) for future readers of this post.

Comment: @mandy8055 but temani's answer seems wrong based on my experience. i have tried wrapping the variable in quotes and even used `toString()` to enforce the fact that its a string, but this doesnt work. maybe it doesnt work because we are using the `FontFace` constructor instead of `@font-face` in css? but this is speculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `font-family` property does not accept font names that start with a number(if unquoted)<sup>1</sup>.

To make it work you can put it in quotes. Something like:

```js
fontList.forEach(font => {
    // ...rest

  ff.load().then(
    () => document.fonts.add(ff),
    err => console.error('ERROR:', err)
  )

  fontNameElement.style.setProperty('--font-family', `'${font.newFileName}'`);
  fontNameElement.style.fontFamily = 'var(--font-family)'

  ...
});
```

---

##### References:

1. [Valid Font Family names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#valid_family_names)
2. [Font Family property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#font-family-prop)
3. [Examples of valid identifier names<sup>*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ident#examples)

<sub>***** Not related to this post but good to refer</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941991/8620333

Comment: and a `font-family` or `--var` value is considered an identifier? @TemaniAfif

Comment: you are considering them as identifier

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for clarifying. I was reading on some docs so took time to respond to your comment. I got what you're referring and you're very correct thanks again.

Comment: now it's unfair to update your answer to copy mine ... plus the OP accepted *your* previous answer. Stack Overflow is made to have "multiple" answers not to copy other ansewrs

Comment: @TemaniAfif let me delete my answer. I will write to OP to unaccept my answer.

Comment: no need to delete it, keep your old answer that the OP accepted. you can edit it if you want but don't update it to make a new one

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you see in my older answer(the `Map` one) from the edit, I have added the quotes because of which it may have worked for OP. but the explanation and my understanding was incorrect so actually I do believe there is no point in keeping the older one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need prefixes if you make sure the value is kept a string inside the variable.

One way (among many) is to add quotes around it

```js
var FontName = '123';

document.body.style.setProperty('--font-family', "'"+FontName+"'")
document.body.style.fontFamily = 'var(--font-family)'
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "123";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Inconsolata Regular"), local("Inconsolata-Regular"), url(https://css-challenges.com/wp-content/themes/ronneby_child/css/QldKNThLqRwH-OJ1UHjlKGlZ5qg.woff2) format("woff2");
}

body {
  font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
Hello World
```

Comment: i tried adding quotes. i also tried `toString()`. nothing worked except prefixing it -.-a thx for ur responses nonetheless!

Comment: maybe it will not work in my case because i am using the `FontFace` constructor instead of applying the style directly in CSS?